# Calculate size of regular polygon based on area

Tags: trigonometry

I have a software problem, where I would like to be able to generate a regular polygon, ideally of arbitrary points, to match the area of a circle, given a particular radius.

To give a little more context, I'll be using this for spatial queries with MySQL, to determine how many points of interest exist within a certain distance of a starting point.

I understand that the more points I add, the closer the polygon will be to approximating a circle. However to improve performance of the application, I would prefer to keep the number points relatively low.

So for example, a circle of radius 50km covers an area of 7853km2.

I would like to figure out, how large an octagon (for example) would need to be, to match that area.

To simplify it, I can break this octagon down into 16 right angle triangles, each with one interior acute angle of 22.5 degrees.

In this case, I think what I really want to know is the length of the hypotenuse.

It seems like it aught to be trivial, but I haven't been able find an equation to do it.

Update:
Just in case this is helpful for someone, based on the answer below, I've written the following MySQL statement, to calculate the required polygon radius based on the number of points and the equivalent circle radius...

```
SET polygon_radius = SQRT(((2*PI()*POWER(circle_radius,2))/number_polygon_sides)/SIN(RADIANS(360/number_polygon_sides)));
```

I'm not totally sure if there may be a more concise/efficient way to write it, but it works correctly, so that's all I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just break it down into $8$ triangles with a common vertex at the octagon's centre.

Those triangles have two sides equal to $r$ and a pointed angle of $45^\circ$

By the way I label it as $r$ since that would be the radius of a circle circumscribed on that octagon. So you want:

$\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot r^2 \sin 45 \cdot 8=\pi \cdot 50^2$

I think that's a far easier bargain.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me create the code to calculate the new radius. I've updated the answer to show the solution.

Comment: @ You're welcome.